# provision a serial console on a VM for virtual appliance using virt-install

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I have a virtual appliance(`qcow2` image) which requires serial console on a VM. In other words, I do not need to install anything. I simply need to boot up the VM from this `qcow2` disk and access the virtual appliance via serial interface. Is it possible to do this with `virt-install`? When I add the `--extra-args="console=ttyS0,115200"` to `virt-install`, then it requires me to specify a `--location`. Is there a workaround to boot up a virtual machine with serial enabled using `virt-install`, but not specifying a distribution tree installation source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, though there are multiple steps to adding a serial console.

`--extra-args` can only be used in combination with `--location`.  As you are working from a local `qcow2` disk image, `--location` is not actually the mechanism you are looking for.

Instead you are looking for `--console`:

#### console:

```
--console
  Connect a text console between the guest and host. Certain guest and 
  hypervisor combinations can automatically set up a getty in the guest, so an
  out of the box text login can be provided (target_type=xen for xen paravirt
  guests, and possibly target_type=virtio in the future).
```

In practice, this is added as follows (on a modern Linux system):

```
--console pty,target_type=virtio
```

***Note**: You can get more options on available configurations here: [https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsConsole](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsConsole_)*

Since I already had a QCOW2 based appliance prepared, I was able to test this as follows:

```
virt-install --name thing --memory 512 \
    --console pty,target_type=virtio --disk appliance.qcow2 --boot hd
```

Behind the scenes, this is performing a number of additions to the "domain" (an XML file storing the configuration of the host).  For example:

```
<controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
  <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
</controller>

<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/14'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/14'/>
  <target type='virtio' port='0'/>
  <alias name='console0'/>
</console>

<channel type='spicevmc'>
  <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='disconnected'/>
  <alias name='channel0'/>
  <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
</channel>
```

If this does not work, you can also achieve this by editing the boot options *inside* the appliance with a tool like `guestfish`([link](http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html)) or by  specifying the location of the kernel, initrd, and supplying the options manually with `--boot`.  In the case of guestfish, there is even a recipe to achieve what you are looking for: [guestfish-recipies: Edit grub configuration in a VM](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-recipes.1.html#edit-grub-configuration-in-a-vm).

#### boot:

```
--boot 
  Optionally specify the post-install VM boot configuration. This option
  allows specifying a boot device order, permanently booting off
  kernel/initrd with option kernel arguments, and enabling a BIOS boot menu
  (requires libvirt 0.8.3 or later)

       --boot kernel=KERNEL,initrd=INITRD,kernel_args="console=/dev/ttyS0"
           Have guest permanently boot off a local kernel/initrd pair, with the 
           specified kernel options.
```